# Fastest way of fading out entire contents of a canvas to transparency, not other color

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I want to create visualization, where whatever is drawn fades away slowly. This should be continuous, so that content added later will be less faded than old content, like in this picture:

[image]

I don't want to clear entire canvas, I would like to just make everything on it more transparent - then draw any new objects.

My instinct would be to do this in each frame:

```
ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,0)";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

However the problem is that canvas doesn't blend alpha - it uses it for blending the other colors.

How can I get canvas to continuously decrease opacity of everything drawn in it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost definitely looking for [canvas compositing operations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation)! It looks like "destination-in" should achieve what you're looking for.

```js
let canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
let rand = n => Math.floor(Math.random() * n);
setInterval(() => {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(rand(300), rand(120), rand(60), Math.PI * 2, 0);
  ctx.fillStyle = `rgba(${rand(256)}, ${rand(256)}, ${rand(256)}, 1)`;
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
  ctx.fill();
}, 150);

let fadeOut = () => {
  let fadeAmount = 0.002;
  // Note that the colour here doesn't matter! Only the alpha matters.
  // The colour here is red, but you'll see no red appear
  ctx.fillStyle = `rgba(255, 0, 0, ${1 - fadeAmount})`;
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-in';
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 300, 120);
  requestAnimationFrame(fadeOut);
};
requestAnimationFrame(fadeOut);
```

```css
canvas { border: 3px solid #808080; background-color: #000000; }
```

```html
<canvas width="300" height="120"></canvas>
```

Note: When you set `ctx.globalCompositeOperation`, it will apply until you either do `ctx.restore()`, or set `ctx.globalCompositeOperation` to a new value! This is a bit of a gotcha.

Comment: This does not completely fade out the drawings on the canvas as you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/ygwp8t6q/

Answer (score 1):

why you don't decrease the opacity of the canvas and when it reach 0 you erase everything from the canvas then reset the opacity value to 1

Comment: I want it to be continuous, so if you draw a line slowly, it will fade behind your mouse pointer. I tried changing the alpha pixel by pixel, but that's too slow.

Comment: @TomášZato what about saving the coordination of each point the mouse move on with the opacity value like this `{x: x_coordination, y: y_coordination, opacity: opacity}` and push them into an array. and on each `requestAnimationFrame` decrease the opacity value and redraw the points. the points that have an opacity equal to 0 get deleted or just doesn't get drawn. but maybe you will want to use webgl for something like this